# Write in XLSX file without lose XML Map

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, dynamics-nav

I have an xlsx template from Dynamics NAV which I can use to import my data to system.

When I write my data in the template and try to import in NAV I receive an error saying the "The Excel workbook must contain an XML map."

The original file has its XML map attached. But when I edit with my data and save this mapping gets lost.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sheet.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active

sheet["A4"].value = 'Test'
sheet["B4"].value = '1234'

wb.save('test.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Is there a way where I can write new data in the xlsx file and save the changes without losing it?

Comment: It must depend on HOW you writing data to the document.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing and how this relates to xlsxwriter since you don't edit anything with that module and as it is a new workbook it can't lose what it never had.

Comment: I edited with an example of my code. When save the new sheet it keeps the data from the original template, but loses the xml.

Comment: You'd have to do this manually by copying the file between archives and updating the relevant metadata. This is probably all doable using openpyxl but is not for the faint-hearted.